# permissions not work samba4

Tags: directory, home-directory

first time writing but I'm desperate and I think you can help
me ... my English is very bad I speak Spanish ... I install Samba4 on
Ubuntu 12 and all is well, I can join computers to the domain and can
create users. My problem is the permissions, not how they work! I need
the owner capeta have all permissions and other users can see the
contents of the folder and read but not modify or delete ... I can not
get that .. try all combinations of permissions on linux and does not
work .. also try changing the permissions on the Security tab in the
administrator users and groups windows and does not work .. how can I
get the owner has full control and others only see the content without
removing or changing? Thanks for taking the time to help me ...

Answer (score 0):

What Samba version your are using? Can you show the content of your samba4 configuration file (smb.conf)? To enable windows permission in samba4 you need install acl package and modify your /etc/fstab; you can follow the instructions in the wiki:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_4/OS_Requirements

My recommendation is build samba4 by yourself (clone de git repository or download the latest tarball from the official samba site). Also you can use the SerNet repository or if you plan to use Debian, you can use the debian backports repository.

I very important if you can show the result of the samba-tool testparm command.

Check the above and tell me.

Comment: are you able to translate your answer that way also other users of this site can use your solution?

Comment: sorry I forgot to translate. Now my answer is translated. Regards